# Firebase Swift - Ambiguous use of key

Tags: swift, firebase

In Firebase (Swift), I simply need to pull the key for the resulting node set as:

```
print((detailData as AnyObject).key)
```

This used to work as of a few months ago, now the error appears `Ambiguous use of "key"` and the app will not compile

How can I access the key of the node?

**dataDetail:**

```
Snap (3MopWYcckIc5OYZkBBUVwghz2) {
    confirmed = 1;
    phoneNumber = 14024464289;
    selfSendRequest = 1;
    timeInvited = "2016-06-04 15:34:43";
    userName = aUserName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If ***detailData*** is your received Snapshot from Firebase, you can try:-

```
if let snapDict = detailData.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

     let key = detalData.key // your key
     print(snapDict)
    }
```

Comment: you want `3MopWYcckIc5OYZkBBUVwghz2`. Are you programming in Swift 2?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`let key = (snapshot as! FIRDataSnapshot).key`

Comment: I followed the docs as: `let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let username = value?["username"] as! String`